How to Parse and format fields to use a period as decimal separator, without thousand separator in Powershell Script
How to Parse and format fields to use a period as decimal separator, without thousand separator in Powershell Script
Need to covert from European number format to standard format given below
Desired Output should be like adding values to code
Desired Output Example:
"0,6774" → 0.6774
"1,490,967" → 1490.967
"114,9" → 114.9
"1.218,3547" → 1218.3547

My script:
$input = @(
    "0,6774",      # Example with decimal separator as comma
    "1,490,967",   # Example with thousands separator
    "114,9",       # Example with decimal separator as comma
    "1.218,3547"   # Example with both thousands separator and decimal as comma
)
$input | ForEach-Object {
    $formatted = $_ -replace ',', ''
    if ($formatted -match '\d+,\d+') {
        $formatted = $formatted -replace ',', '.'
    }
    $formatted
}


I don't understand your second example of 1,490,967. If this is a number in European format, how can it have multiple decimal separators?

Second comma is thousand separator

I thought European number format used , as the decimal separator and . as the thousands separator (I'm not familiar with any numbering formats that use the same separator with multiple meanings depending on where they appear in the string).

I second what @Bill_Stewart pointed out, "1,490,967" → 1490.967 doesn't make any sense in ANY culture.

B.T.W. Don't use $input as self-declared variable because it is an Automatic variable.

Assuming your intention is to read strings that contain floating point numbers in European format, where . is the number group (thousands) separator and , is the decimal separator, it seems like something like this would work:
$numberFormatInfo = New-Object Globalization.NumberFormatInfo
$numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = ","
$numberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator = "."

[Single]::Parse("0,6774",$numberFormatInfo)      # Outputs 0.6774
[Single]::Parse("1.490,967",$numberFormatInfo)   # Outputs 1490.967
[Single]::Parse("114,9",$numberFormatInfo)       # Outputs 114.9
[Single]::Parse("1.218,3547",$numberFormatInfo)  # Outputs 1218.355


Nice, though I suggest using the higher-precision, more typically used [double] type; alternatively,  [decimal].

Also assuming your second example is a typo, here's another way:
$numbers = @(
    "0,6774",      # Example with decimal separator as comma
    "1.490,967",   # Example with thousands separator
    "114,9",       # Example with decimal separator as comma
    "1.218,3547"   # Example with both thousands separator and decimal as comma
)

$styleIn    = [System.Globalization.NumberStyles]"AllowLeadingSign, AllowDecimalPoint, AllowThousands"
# known culture that uses a decimal comma and a dot for thousand separator
$cultureIn  = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]"nl-NL" 
$cultureOut = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

[decimal]$numberOut = 0
$numbers | ForEach-Object {
    if ([decimal]::TryParse($_, $styleIn, $cultureIn, [ref]$numberOut)) { 
        # $numberOut is now the decimal value itself
        # for display purposes:
        # format "G" --> no thousand separators and decimal point.
        @{$_ = $numberOut.ToString("G", $cultureOut)}
    }
}

Output:
Name                           Value
----                           -----
0,6774                         0.6774
1.490,967                      1490.967
114,9                          114.9
1.218,3547                     1218.3547


A DOY way using regex could be:
$numbers = @(
    "0,6774",      # Example with decimal separator as comma
    "1.490,967",   # Example with thousands separator
    "114,9",       # Example with decimal separator as comma
    "1.218,3547"   # Example with both thousands separator and decimal as comma
)

$culture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$numbers | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^[+-]?(?:(?:0|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:\.[0-9]{3})*)|\d+)(?:,\d+)?$') {
        $numberOut = [decimal]::Parse(($_ -split ',', 2) -replace '[,.]' -join '.', $culture)
    }
    else {
        $numberOut = [decimal]$_
    }
    # for display purposes:
    # format "G" --> no thousand separators and decimal point.
    @{$_ = $numberOut.ToString("G", $culture)}
}

